# Vector field tangent to a singular holomorphic foliation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, several-complex-variables, complex-dynamics

Is there an intuitive way to see that the vector field
$$\begin{equation}
v=\begin{cases}
\dot z=e^{\frac{1}{z}}\\
\dot w=e^{\frac{1}{w}}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}$$ 
is tangent to a singular holomorphic foliation on $\mathbb{C}^2$ with singular set $\Sigma=\{zw = 0\}$?